# Accounting Error - ColdFusion - Won't Add Total

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

Looping through some numbers for doing some accounting.

But when I try add the st.hrs to total - I get an error.
The value '' cannot be converted to a number.

Thought it was because the st.hrs is not present - that is why the recordcount check is there...

Any ideas folks?

```
        <cfloop index = "ul" list = "#templist#">
            <cfset total = 0>
            <cfoutput query="bl">
                <cfquery name="st" datasource="#tds#">
                SELECT * from billstaff
                where billid = '#bl.billid#' and uid = '#ul#'
                </cfquery>
                <cfif st.recordcount is not 0>
                <cfset total = #st.hrs# + total>
                </cfif>
            </cfoutput>
            <cfoutput>#total#</cfoutput><br>
        </cfloop>
```

Comment: The database in question has null values in the total field for some records.  ColdFusion transforms those to empty strings.  Is there any reason you don't use sql's sum() function to get your answer?

Comment: The Null Values i thought I removed with recordcount.  Can u elaborate on the sum()?

Comment: RecordCount just tells you whether the query contains any records. It tells you nothing about the column values in those records. You have to check the individual values. Dan's suggesting you use the aggregate SUM to calculate the total amount in a single query, instead of querying within a loop. You would have to post the SQL for the bl query for specifics.

Comment: Since you don't know what an sql sum() is, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Hmmm... I've also tried len(st.hrs) and st.hrs not "" the error is occuring with total - not with the st.hrs or data query...cfset total = st.hrs +1 works... But cfset total = st.hrs + total errors... The error is on total..

Comment: Fixed... Changed total to ntotal : reserved word?

Comment: No. At a guess, could `total` be the name of a column in one of the queries, and is the value null? If so, since `total` is unscoped, the query value would take precedence over `variables.total` causing the error you are seeing.  RE: *also tried len(st.hrs) and st.hrs not ""* Since the goal is to verify the value is numeric, isNumeric() would be a more appropriate check. Having said that, querying within a loop is inefficient. Better to use SUM as suggested. Also, any queries should use cfqueryparam, both for sql-i protection and performance.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

If you just need to calculate a total, go with Dan's suggestion of using a single query, with a basic [SUM()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) aggregate. I will let Dan elaborate, but that would be more efficient than querying within a loop.

**Longer answer:**

Just to address the original error, this is a good example of why scoping variables is a good practice. The absence of scoping is what caused the fatal error. However, it could just as easily cause logic errors, which are not as easy to spot.

Initializing the `total` variable without a scope, means it ends up in the default `variables` scope. So you are essentially doing this:

> `<cfset variables.total = 0>`

When you loop through the outer query, the data in the current row gets assigned to variables, but in a different scope: the (psuedo) query scope. Since one of the query columns happens to be named `total`, the loop inadvertently **creates a second `total` variable**, which causes things go sideways when you try and calculate the sum here:

> `<cfset total = #st.hrs# + total>`

Since the `total` variable is not scoped, CF has to guess which of the two it should use, and in this case, guesses wrong.

Variables without a scope are [evaluated according to these rules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-%20%207fdf.html), which give the query scope a higher priority than `variables`. As a result, CF uses the `bl.total` value instead of `variables.total`. Since `bl.total` is null (or an empty string), that causes the *"value '' cannot be converted to a number* error. Specifying the variable scope, ie `variables.total`, would prevent that error.

Again, there are better ways to simply calculate a sum. However, when you really do need a query loop, be sure to scope all variables to avoid potential conflicts.